# Recreate models using Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to recreate the models in database after dropping everything in it.

Mongoose (or Mongo itself )actually recreates the documents but not the indices. So is there a way to reset Mongoose so that it can recreate indices as if running the first time?

The reason why I'm using dropDatabase is because it seems easier while testing. Otherwise I would have to remove all collections one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While not recommended for production use, depending on your scenario, you can add the `index` property to a field definition to specify you want an index created:

```
var animalSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  type: String,
  tags: { type: [String], index: true } // field level
});

animalSchema.index({ name: 1, type: -1 }); // schema level
```

Or,

```
var s = new Schema({ name: { type: String, sparse: true })
Schema.path('name').index({ sparse: true });
```

Or, you can call `ensureIndex` on the `Model` ([docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.ensureIndexes)):

```
Animal.ensureIndexes(function (err) {
    if (err) return handleError(err);
});
```

Comment: I switched to an approach where I drop the test database via a script before testing starts. But just as a feedback, your first solution does not work either. I think once a model is created, it caches it and does not check for indices. The ensureIndexes method may work, so I'm accepting this as an answer.